# Sending arguments to function as response - why not coming?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I came up that in JS list of arguments is send to another function this way - am I wrong?

```
func(parameters.response.items)
```

Code

```
Request('friends.get', {fields: 'photo_100', count: 5, v: 5.95}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    Draw(data.response.items);
})

function Draw(friends) {
    $('#some').html(friends[1].id);
}
```

The whole proyect is available on http://77.246.157.26/

Error in browser console `TypeError: friends[1] is undefined`
but `console.log()` prints all correctly and completely

Comment: It's a free hosting site

Comment: That's because the json returned is an object with one key. and its error. Make sure to check if no error is returned before trying to add html in #some.

Comment: What does data (or at least data.response.items) look like?

Comment: The data example http://prntscr.com/nslotc

Comment: `data.response.items` would have to be an Array, that is a property of a `response` Object, that is a property of your JSON `data` response Object, for this to make any sense.

Comment: So what is missing, @StackSlave? The data sequency is kept correctly, as I see.

Answer (score 0):

Went to your site, checked it real quick.

The data from your AJAX call is getting an error..

```
jQuery33105943325674648605_1558658520581({"error":{"error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: access_token was given to another ip address.","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"friends.get"},{"key":"fields","value":"photo_100"},{"key":"count","value":"5"},{"key":"v","value":"5.95"},{"key":"callback","value":"jQuery33105943325674648605_1558658520581"},{"key":"_","value":"1558658520582"}]}});
```

Check for error first:

```
Request('friends.get', {fields: 'photo_100', count: 5, v: 5.95}, function(data) {
    if(!data.error) {
        //console.log(data);
        if(data.response.items) {
            Draw(data.response.items);
        } else {
            console.log("Unexpected json object format.");
        }
    } else {
        alert(data.error.error_msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm surprised, bit console is not catching the error, even you propose 2 places. About the AJAX error I don't see that. Where could you?